# Source port with default fallback value?

Tags: xproc

I have an XProc step where I would like the input source to work like this:

- if a URL is provided on the command line using `-isource=foo.xml`, then the document at that URL is used as the source document;
- if no URL is provided, then the document `default.xml` should be used.

Is it possible to obtain this behaviour in XProc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Florent on the [XProc mailing list](http://markmail.org/message/z3p3rwlmbgxy32av), using a p:document inside the p:input works just fine as a default. Specifying something else from outside simply overrides it:

```
<p:declare-step version="1.0" xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc"
    name="main">

    <p:input port="source">
        <p:document href="default.xml"/>
    </p:input>
    <p:output port="result"/>

    <p:identity/>

</p:declare-step>
```

Run it with:

```
calabash test.xpl
```

and:

```
calabash --input source=myinput.xml test.xpl
```

to see the difference..

HTH!